# python identation error (2.7.5)

Tags: python, python-2.7

im new in programming and i just started learning python (2.7.5) and im facing this indentation error, i've tried to change the position but still the same , and in the options is set automatically to 4 spaces. what should i do?

```
if temperature>60 and temperature<75:
print "just right!"
else:

File "<pyshell#8>", line 3
  else:
    ^
```

IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Indent the line with `print`? I can't really tell, since you may have made a copy-paste mistake.

Comment: make sure your indentation is consistent, it sometimes happens that one line is indented with tab and the next with number of spaces.

Comment: The way your code is indented it should give an indentation error on the `print` line already... Did you type this in an interactive shell? If so, which one? Copy your exact input and output.

Comment: Protip, unrelated to your problem: Use `if 60 < temperature < 75:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to indent everything after the if line:

```
if temperature>60 and temperature<75:
    print "just right!"
else:
    print "not right!"
```

make sure that all the indents are of the same space width (standard is 4 spaces as you said).

Indentation errors happen when the indentation is of different width like so:

```
if temperature>60 and temperature<75:
    print "just right!"
  else:
    print "not right!"
```

Note that no indentation is also an indentation level, like the if and the else in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

As Serbitar said, indentation is extremely important in Python. As you don't use semi-colons like in other languages, Python pays particular attention to indentation.

It also encourages clean code. There are a few situations where indentation isn't important.
Eg:

```
class ClassName:

    def method_name():
        print("I am a really long string," \
                "So where you indent the second line doesn't"\
                      "matter")
```

This also applies to method calls. If you are calling a method where the arguments are particularly long, it doesn't matter where you format the second line. 
However, it's always recommended to format appropriately. 
If you use the community edition of PyCharm, it helps a great deal with this issue.